# Does PHP close SQL connections opened with PDO at the end of the script if I don't explicitly close it?

Tags: php, sql, pdo, connection, database-connection

I know I can close a PDO SQL connection setting the handler to `NULL`.

But if I don't do that, does PHP close the connection at the end of the script?

Fore example, can I use

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:db.sqlite');
/* Code */
if ($cond1) { exit; }
/* More code */
if ($cond2) { exit; }
/* ... */
$db = NULL;
/* Code not related to the database */
```

... or should I use this:

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite:db.sqlite');
/* Code */
if ($cond1) {
    $db = NULL;
    exit;
}
/* More code */
if ($cond2) {
    $db = NULL;
    exit;
}
/* ... */
$db = NULL;
/* Code not related to the database */
```

Comment: Yes, run it 1000 times and watch memory usage to verify.

Comment: Yes, but it's a good practice to close explicitly it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the **[docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)**:

> The connection remains active for the lifetime of that PDO object. To
>   close the connection, you need to destroy the object by ensuring that
>   all remaining references to it are deleted--you do this by assigning
>   NULL to the variable that holds the object. If you don't do this
>   explicitly, **PHP will automatically close the connection when your
>   script ends**.

Answer (score 1):

**EXAMPLE.**

This is your dbc class

```
<?php

class dbc {

    public $dbserver = 'server';
    public $dbusername = 'user';
    public $dbpassword = 'pass';
    public $dbname = 'db';

    function openDb() {    
        try {
            $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->dbserver . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname . ';charset=utf8', '' . $this->dbusername . '', '' . $this->dbpassword . '');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            die("error, please try again");
        }        
        return $db;
    }

    function getAllData($qty) {
        //prepared query to prevent SQL injections
        $query = "select * from TABLE where qty = ?";
        $stmt = $this->openDb()->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $qty, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $rows;
    }    
?>
```

your PHP page:

```
<?php 
require "dbc.php";

$getList = $db->getAllData(25);

foreach ($getList as $key=> $row) {
         echo $row['columnName'] .' key: '. $key;
    }
```

Your connection will be closed as soon as the results are returned

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) When you call exit:

> Terminates execution of the script. Shutdown functions and object destructors will always be executed even if exit is called.

This means your PDO connection will be closed. It's always good practice to close it yourself though.